# In Oracle, will certain users only be able to see certain data in the privileges tables?

Tags: oracle, permissions

I can view data in the table_privileges view logged in as a particular user, but it seems to be missing or different information when logged in as a different user.

For the privileges views (data created when calling GRANT), will users see the data differently in these views? I seem to recall reading that this was the case, but can't confirm now.

Any specific links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table_privileges view is only preserved for compatibility with ancient versions of Oracle.

You should instead be using the [user_tab_privs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2661.htm) view, [all_tab_privs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2099.htm) view, or [dba_tab_privs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2365.htm) view (documentation links for each when you click).

Comment: Reading the documentation, the answer seems to be "yes". But thanks for the links, they are indeed helpful.

Comment: The documentation links were the best way of answering the question. No point in me cutting and pasting :) Your other question on this site actually has an answer that applies to many data dictionary views. ALL_% views show you things you've permission to use/see, USER_% views show you things you own (ish) and DBA_% views show you everything.